# perform division but get data type unchanged

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
if target % 3 == 0:
    counter = Counter(nums)
    logging.debug(f"counter: {counter}")
    dup = target/3
    if counter[dup] >= 3:
        triplets.append([dup]*3)
```

which produce

```
 [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
```

Then I have to cast it back to integer

```
  int(target/3)
```

I should be very careful about the automatic behavior of `divider`,
How could perform divide operation but get data type unchanged?

Comment: Use integer division, `dup = target // 3`?

Comment: That will only work with Integer othe data types might change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the type of the initial variable you could check what that type is and perform different calculations for each.

```
def divideNumber(myNum):
    if isinstance(myNum,int):
        return myNum // 3
    elif isinstance(myNum,float):
        return myNum/3
```